# Crash on Launch, all solutions found do not work

Tags: error

Recently rebuilt my computer, new SSD, latest GPU driver, C++ libraries installed, every other program and games run just fine. Blender, however, starts and crashes within a few clicks or if opening/minimizing other windows. I've been googling solutions and trying them all night but to no avail.

Tried running most recent build both install and from zip. Tried running 2.78, both installed and from zip. Ran via administrator, no addons have been added, installed Python, halted anti-virus program, ran via CMD, replaced the version_update.py file, ran with the opengl32.dll file placed alongside the .exe and the program still crashed; basically any solution google handed to me I went through.

No matter which way I try to run blender it crashes and prints to CMD:

```
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Windows 7 x64
i5 6600k
Radeon RX 480
16GB RAM

Blender ran just fine on this system with my old hardrive, I upgraded to this new SSD and suddenly Blender is throwing this issue at me. Help please?

Comment: It would be better if you report a bug by following the instructions on https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/